# Extensions won't show after buildout and restart

Tags: plone, buildout, egg, zeos

I'm trying to install an egg in my Plone 4.3.1 environment (with ZEO).

So I added the line "collective.quickupload" to my buildout.cfg file and ran buildout by using the following command:

```
/usr/local/Plone/zeocluster# sudo -E -u plone_buildout ./bin/buildout
```

Here's what I got:

```
Updating zeoserver.
Updating client1.
Updating client2.
 Updating backup.
 Updating zopepy.
 Updating unifiedinstaller.
 Updating precompiler.
 Compiling Python files.
 Compiling locale files.
 Error while compiling /usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/python_gettext-1.2-py2.7.egg/pythongettext/tests/test_escape.po
 Error while compiling /usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/python_gettext-1.2-py2.7.egg/pythongettext/tests/test5.po
 Updating setpermissions.
 setpermissions: Running 
# Dummy references to force this to execute after referenced parts
 echo /usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/var/backups yes > /dev/null
 chmod 600 .installed.cfg
# Make sure anything we've created in var is r/w by our group
 find /usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/var -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; 2> /dev/null
 find /usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/var -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; 2> /dev/null
 find /usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/var -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; 2> /dev/null
 find /usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/var -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; 2> /dev/null
 chmod 754 /usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/bin/*
*************** PICKED VERSIONS ****************
[versions]
 collective.quickupload = 1.6.1
 ua-parser = 0.3.4

*************** /PICKED VERSIONS ***************
```

Then, I restarted my Plone instance by using:
    ./bin/plonectl restart

Restarting worked fine, but the extension is not shown in the extensions List in Plone.

I also tried to start zeoserver, client1 and client2 in fg-mode. This didn't work. I got the following error:
    [...]

```
File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.lockfile-1.0.2-py2.7.egg/zc/lockfile/__init__.py", line 59, in _lock_file
raise LockError("Couldn't lock %r" % file.name)
zc.lockfile.LockError: Couldn't lock '/usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/var/filestorage/Data.fs.lock'
```

Thanks a lot for your feedbacks!

Comment: The fg mode error is likely because something is still running in the background.

Comment: Do you think a Plone/Zeo process is still running?

Comment: Try ./bin/restartcluster.sh this will restart the zeoserver and all clients.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer Jihaisse.
But I don't have the commande restartcluster.sh in the bin directory

Comment: @AlexMiccoli It could also be that you were running with the wrong user, or that your file permissions has become incorrect.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers.

I restarted the server (again), changed the IP address and port of ZEO in buildout.cfg and started the instance normally.

Now it seems to work.

I guess you were all right: Another process was using the same port. Despite I tried to show the running processes and it wasn't in the list.

Because of my "newbie"-status on Stackowerflow, I cannot answer my own question within some hours. I'll answer and close it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answers. I restarted the server (again), changed the IP address and port of ZEO in buildout.cfg and started the instance normally. Now it seems to work. I guess you were all right: Another process was using the same port. Despite I tried to show the running processes and it wasn't in the list.